# Iframe popups not closing properly in IE10

Tags: highslide

After the latest set of updates Microsoft pushed out yesterday (April 10, 2013), we're having issues with highslide pop-ups that use iframes with embedded FlowPlayer videos not closing properly/fully. The popup partially closes and leaves a box with the video still playing in the background.

The pop-ups work fine in other browsers (even IE10 in compatibility mode).  I tested on an IE10 system that does not have the latest updates and it works fine.

Sample URL to see the issue: http://www.cliptraining.com/toc.cfm?category=Excel_2010

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! You're more likely to get a response if you include what you've done so far in trying to solve the problem yourself. Also, there's no clear question here... just a problem statement.

Comment: No problem with JW Player or a YouTube video in the iframe, so this apparently relates to FlowPlayer, specifically. FWIW, I am seeing the same problem in IE10 (updated yesterday).

Comment: @bradym: In the world of Highslide JS, there's nothing wrong with this question. The question is implicit: "How do I fix this?" And given the density of the Highslide JS script, there's little a user could do to try to fix the problem himself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited answer:

For a single expander, i.e., one that is NOT part of a slideshow gallery, adding this appears to fix it:

hs.objectLoadTime = 'after';

If you have a gallery (i.e., a series of expanders that include next/previous navigation), the problem becomes a bit more complex. The brute force fix appears to be, in addition to the single expander fix:

hs.transitions = ['fade'];

I still need to do some controlled experiments to narrow things down.

Comment: EarlyOut, Thank you.  I have tried your above suggestions, and I get the same results.  Actually with hs.restoreDuration set to zero, it's even worse.  I tried on a computer without the latest updates and Highslide worked fine, then I installed the update (KB2817183) and now the popups do not close fully.  Highslide is working properly in all other browsers. This leads me to believe that this is an issue where a Microsoft change has broken part of Highslide.

Comment: One more thing to try: hs.objectLoadTime = 'after';

Comment: The Windows update breaks many more things than are mentioned in this discussion, including the JW Player script. It even manages to mangle some aspects of the YouTube player when it's placed in an iframe and opened in Highslide JS. The only solution is to remove KB2817183 and turn off automatic updates so you don't get the same buggy update again.